# Object Required error on line no 6

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am getting Object Required error on line no 6. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
Dim row As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim lR As Long
Dim flag As Boolean
Set sheet = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set lR = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Rows.Count

For a = 1 To lR
    For i = 1 To lR
        Set row = sheet.Rows(i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
            flag = True
            sheet.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next a
If flag = False Then
MsgBox "No Empty Rows Found"
End If
```

Comment: Set lR = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Rows.Count in this line I am getting error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *Set* a long integer to a .Count. Simply use **=** to assign the value. Additionally, you want the xlCellTypeLastCell's row number; not the number of rows it is on (which will always be 1).

```
lR = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

Alternately as,

```
lR = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove 'Set' and it will work as we only use "Set" when we declare a vairable as object. like sheet as worksheet (here worksheet is an object)
not like lr as long (long is a datatype, not an object).

Instead of 
Set lR = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Rows.Count

write -
lR = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Rows.Count

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that the [xlCellTypeLastCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) can occupy more than a single row.

Comment: Please rate my answer @Sougata, if it helped you. :)